# How to get the high (over 16 bits) part of an address from a label in gpasm

Tags: assembly, embedded, pic, gpasm

I want to retrieve the high (over 16 bits) part of an address from a label in gpasm code.

Here is my small example `test.asm`:

```
    LIST P=PIC18F46Q10
    ;LIST P=PIC18F47J13

    ORG 0

    MOVLW TEST_LOCATION & 0xFF
    MOVWF 0x500, A
    MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> 8) & 0xFF
    MOVWF 0x501, A
    MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> 16) & 0xFF
    MOVWF 0x502, A

JUST_LOOP
    BRA JUST_LOOP

    ORG 0x12468
TEST_LOCATION
    DB 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF

    END
```

The aim of this code is to store the address of `TEST_LOCATION` (`0x12468`) to some part of the RAM.

Assembler version:

```
D:\Temp>gpasm -v
gpasm-1.5.2 #1325 (Jan 30 2022)
```

Assemble command:

```
gpasm test.asm
```

Here is a part of resulting `test.lst`:

```
LOC    OBJECT CODE    LINE  SOURCE TEXT
  VALUE

                      00001         LIST P=PIC18F46Q10
                      00002         ;LIST P=PIC18F47J13
                      00003 
000000                00004         ORG 0
                      00005 
000000 0E68           00006         MOVLW TEST_LOCATION & 0xFF
Message[1302]: RAM Bank undefined in this chunk of code. Ensure that bank bits are correct. Assuming bank 5 from now on.
000002 6E00           00007         MOVWF 0x500, A
000004 0E24           00008         MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> 8) & 0xFF
000006 6E01           00009         MOVWF 0x501, A
000008 0E00           00010         MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> 16) & 0xFF
00000A 6E02           00011         MOVWF 0x502, A
                      00012 
00000C                00013 JUST_LOOP
00000C D7FF           00014         BRA JUST_LOOP
                      00015 
012468                00016         ORG 0x12468
012468                00017 TEST_LOCATION
Warning[220]: Address exceeds maximum range for this processor. BADROM_START: 0x010000 <= Bad address: 0x012468 <= BADROM_END: 0x30FFFF
Warning[220]: Address exceeds maximum range for this processor. BADROM_START: 0x010000 <= Bad address: 0x012469 <= BADROM_END: 0x30FFFF
Warning[220]: Address exceeds maximum range for this processor. BADROM_START: 0x010000 <= Bad address: 0x01246A <= BADROM_END: 0x30FFFF
Warning[220]: Address exceeds maximum range for this processor. BADROM_START: 0x010000 <= Bad address: 0x01246B <= BADROM_END: 0x30FFFF
012468 ADDE EFBE      00018         DB 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF
                      00019 
                      00020         END
```

You can see the middle part `0x24` and the lower part `0x68` from the address `0x12468` are correctly embed into the instructions, but the high part `0x01` didn't get embed and zero is stored instead.

I thought that this may be because `PIC18F46Q10`, which has 64k-byte program ROM and doesn't have storage at `0x12468`, is selected, so I tried switching to `PIC18F47J13`, which has 128k-byte program ROM. However, the high part still got embed as zero.

A part of resulting `test.lst` for this case:

```
LOC    OBJECT CODE    LINE  SOURCE TEXT
  VALUE

                      00001         ;LIST P=PIC18F46Q10
                      00002         LIST P=PIC18F47J13
                      00003 
000000                00004         ORG 0
                      00005 
000000 0E68           00006         MOVLW TEST_LOCATION & 0xFF
Message[1302]: RAM Bank undefined in this chunk of code. Ensure that bank bits are correct. Assuming bank 5 from now on.
000002 6E00           00007         MOVWF 0x500, A
000004 0E24           00008         MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> 8) & 0xFF
000006 6E01           00009         MOVWF 0x501, A
000008 0E00           00010         MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> 16) & 0xFF
00000A 6E02           00011         MOVWF 0x502, A
                      00012 
00000C                00013 JUST_LOOP
00000C D7FF           00014         BRA JUST_LOOP
                      00015 
012468                00016         ORG 0x12468
012468                00017 TEST_LOCATION
012468 ADDE EFBE      00018         DB 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF
                      00019 
                      00020         END
```

What should I do to get the high part of the address `0x01` from the label `TEST_LOCATION` with gpasm?

Writing `0x01` directly without using `TEST_LOCATION` can be a workaround, but it doesn't look nice.

Comment: Did you try the operators `UPPER`, `HIGH`, and `LOW`? See the manual for details. -- However, this does not explain the strange result. According to the manual, expressions are evaluated as 32-bit values.

Comment: @thebusybee `UPPER` looks working and it looks better than manually writing the expressions. Thank you.

Comment: @thebusybee I finally found the reason of the behavior! (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use provided operators, you can obtain the bytes of the address:

```
    MOVLW LOW TEST_LOCATION
    MOVWF 0x500, A
    MOVLW HIGH TEST_LOCATION
    MOVWF 0x501, A
    MOVLW UPPER TEST_LOCATION
    MOVWF 0x502, A
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification of gpasm, the shift width `16` is interpreted as a hexadecimal number having value 22 in decimal.

The expression can be fixed by using a decimal number

```
    MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> D'16') & 0xFF
```

or using a hexadecimal number

```
    MOVLW (TEST_LOCATION >> 0x10) & 0xFF
```

Comment: Oh, really?! :facepalm: